# screenOrientation abnormal in huawei P20

Tags: android, orientation, onconfigurationchanged

Activity A , B
android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" in  A;
android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"  in  B;

startActivity A->B,then press back key to Activity A , A's orientation will First vertical screen and then horizontal screen，and  activity A's  onConfigurationChanged method invoke twice.

It should be directly turned into a horizontal screen. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the device system to solve the issue!